# big gray box on screen

Tags: html, css

There's a gray box on the middle of my website. I've double checked all of the code, and I can't figure out what's creating this. I'm sorry for asking such a stupid question, I'm quite new to this. Here's the code -

```css
.nav a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.jumbotron {
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top:100px;
}

.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.jumbotron {
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top:100px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}


.learn-more h3 {
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.learn-more a {
  color: #00b0ff;
}

.neighborhoood-guides {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb
}









 
.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
 
/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#fff;
}
 
.menu {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
 
.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
}
 
.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:black;
}
 
.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:dodgerblue;
}
 
.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}
 
/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:11px;
    
}
 
.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    
}
 
.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:#fff;
}
 
/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}
 
.sub-menu {
    width:160%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#fff;
}
 
.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:11px;
}
 
.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:bold
}
 
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:#fff;
}

.neighborhood-guides h2 {
  font-size: 48px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.neighborhood-guides p {
  font-size: 24px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
    }

.socialmedia {
background: #498FCC;

}

.neighborhood-guides {
padding: 20px 20px;
}

.allrights li p {
color: white;
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
}

.whole {
 background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/3ay8hjS.jpg');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div class="whole">
  <head>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    
  </head>

  <body>
 <div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Contact Us</a></li>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Destinations <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Airlines</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
           <li><a href="#">Cruiselines</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Weddings & Honeymoons</a></li>
            <li>
                
                <a href="#">Useful Information <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
 
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Travel Insurance</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                </ul>
            
            </nav>
        
</div>       
        

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
      </div>
    </div> 
   <center>
<h2></h2>
        <p></p>
        <h1></h1>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="Thumbnail">
    <img src="">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="Thumbnail">
   <img src="">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="Thumbnail">
    <image src="">
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        </center>
 
<center>
    <div class="learn-more">
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
   <h3></h3>
   <p></p>
   <p><a href="#"></a></p>
       </div>
    <div class ="col-md-4">
   <h3></h3>
   <p>.</p>
   <p><a href="#"></a></p>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-md-4">
   <h3></h3>
   <p></p>
   <p><a href="#"></a></p>
    </div>
     </div>
 </div>
         </center>
</div>      
       
       
       
       
       
       <div class="socialmedia">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          
                </ul>
            </nav>   
</div>       
       
       <center>
       <h2></h2>
       <h2></h2>
       <h2></h2>
       </center>
       <h2></h2>
       <h2></h2>
        <div class="socialmedia">
       <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
       <div class="allrights">
            <center><li><p>Travel Away Corporation All Rights Reserved 2015</p></li></center>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
            </nav>
       </div>
       </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see any: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/kphe5fbL/16/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following attribute: `background-color: #eee; */`, otherwise, I've put your same code on the fiddle and didn't see any issue.

Replace your .jumbotron class with this

```
.jumbotron {
        padding: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        color: inherit;
        }
```

Whenever you have such a problem, right click on your mouse and select *Inspect element* and then click on the html element (which has css applied on it) and see which properties are checked and which are not. You should easily fix your problem then.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question because you don't say what you want to appear there instead of this large grey square, but to answer your specific question: remove the jumbotron markup from the HTML and it will disappear:

```css
.nav a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.jumbotron {
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top:100px;
}

.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.jumbotron {
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top:100px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}


.learn-more h3 {
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.learn-more a {
  color: #00b0ff;
}

.neighborhoood-guides {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb
}









 
.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
 
/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#fff;
}
 
.menu {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
 
.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
}
 
.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:black;
}
 
.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:dodgerblue;
}
 
.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}
 
/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:11px;
    
}
 
.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    
}
 
.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:#fff;
}
 
/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}
 
.sub-menu {
    width:160%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#fff;
}
 
.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:11px;
}
 
.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:bold
}
 
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:#fff;
}

.neighborhood-guides h2 {
  font-size: 48px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.neighborhood-guides p {
  font-size: 24px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
    }

.socialmedia {
background: #498FCC;

}

.neighborhood-guides {
padding: 20px 20px;
}

.allrights li p {
color: white;
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
}

.whole {
 background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/3ay8hjS.jpg');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div class="whole">
  <head>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    
  </head>

  <body>
 <div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Contact Us</a></li>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Destinations <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Airlines</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
           <li><a href="#">Cruiselines</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Weddings & Honeymoons</a></li>
            <li>
                
                <a href="#">Useful Information <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
 
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Travel Insurance</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                </ul>
            
            </nav>
        
</div>       
        

   
   <center>
<h2></h2>
        <p></p>
        <h1></h1>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="Thumbnail">
    <img src="">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="Thumbnail">
   <img src="">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="Thumbnail">
    <image src="">
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        </center>
 
<center>
    <div class="learn-more">
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
   <h3></h3>
   <p></p>
   <p><a href="#"></a></p>
       </div>
    <div class ="col-md-4">
   <h3></h3>
   <p>.</p>
   <p><a href="#"></a></p>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-md-4">
   <h3></h3>
   <p></p>
   <p><a href="#"></a></p>
    </div>
     </div>
 </div>
         </center>
</div>      
       
       
       
       
       
       <div class="socialmedia">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          
                </ul>
            </nav>   
</div>       
       
       <center>
       <h2></h2>
       <h2></h2>
       <h2></h2>
       </center>
       <h2></h2>
       <h2></h2>
        <div class="socialmedia">
       <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
       <div class="allrights">
            <center><li><p>Travel Away Corporation All Rights Reserved 2015</p></li></center>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
            </nav>
       </div>
       </div>
  </body>
</html>
```